# Merging a .bak to an existing SQL database

Tags: sql-server, restore

I have a SQL Server database with data from 1990-2018 in a `.mdf` file.

I recently downloaded data for 2018-2020 and it's in a `.bak` file.

When I went to "Restore" the database, it wiped out all the data from 1990-2018 and just replaced it with the new one (2018-2020).

How do I merge an existing `.mdf` and a new `.bak` file? Or am I just thinking about this wrong?

Comment: You'll need to **(1)** restore the `.bak` under a different name, and then **(2)** merge the contents of the two databases using some SQL code  - there's no direct "restore and merge" functionality in SQL Server - a restore always overwrites the whole database (if one is already present)

Answer (score 1):

A single database restore is not the operation you need if your goal is the merge data. You are looking for a data level solution not a database level solution.

SQL tooling can help you with this task, but it is not required (it depends on knowledge and skill level). The 2 data compare tools I have used Red Gate SQL Data Compare and Apex SQL Data Diff have the ability to compare data using a .bak file. After the comparison the tool can generate the 'deployment' or 'change' script that you could use to "merge" in your changes.

TSQL solution: Craft a merge statement for each table. This would require restoring your backup file to another Database name.  This will result in 2 databases (source and target) living on the SQL Server.

TSQL Merge docs:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

To avoid a database overwrite specify a new destination (non-existing) database name in your restore command. (included SSMS screen shot)
[image]